# Why “le” behind?

Tags: grammaire

I’m reading Assimil New French with Ease, where its last lesson says

> Reprenez le livre tous les jours et feuilletez-le.

, which means “Take the book again everyday and flip through it”.

But why the *le* is after “feuilletez”? I thought it shall always be in front of the verb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pronoun is after the verb when the imperative mood is used at the affirmative:

> *Feuillete-le*
>   *Feuilletons-le*
>   *Feuilletez-le*
>   *Prend-le*
>   *Prenons-le*
>   *Prenez-le*
>   *Vas-y*
>   *Allons-y*
>   ...

At the negative, it is located before it:

> *Ne le feuilletez pas*
>   *N'y va pas*

At other moods, the pronoun is also before the verb:

> *Vous le feuilletez*
>   *Tu y vas*

Comment: Perhaps the most common phrase that's similarly constructed is *"Allons-y"*, rather than *"Y allons"*.

Answer (score 0):

`Reprenez le livre tous les jours et feuilletez` means `Take the book again everyday and flip`.

`Reprenez le livre tous les jours et feuilletez-le` means `Take the book again everyday and flip through it`

Le verbe "feuilleter" a besoin d'un COD. `feuilletez-le` signifie "feuilletez le livre". `Reprenez le livre tous les jours et feuilletez` n'est pas clair : qu'est-ce que nous devons feuilleter? Comparer avec : `Reprenez le livre tous les jours et feuilletez ce cahier` ou `Reprenez les livres tous les jours et feuilletez-les`.